# How to retrieve list of all possible ner_tags classes that stanford nlp module classifies?

Tags: nlp, nltk, stanford-nlp

I want to see all possible ner_tags that stanford nlp classifies the text into, such as PERSON,LOCATION, ORGANIZATION, TITLE etc, where can I find those, any pointers are much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

From Stanford NER docs, http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/CRF-NER.shtml:

> **Models**
>
> Included with Stanford NER are a 4 class model trained on the CoNLL
>   2003 eng.train, a 7 class model trained on the MUC 6 and MUC 7
>   training data sets, and a 3 class model trained on both data sets and
>   some additional data (including ACE 2002 and limited amounts of
>   in-house data) on the intersection of those class sets. (The training
>   data for the 3 class model does not include any material from the
>   CoNLL eng.testa or eng.testb data sets, nor any of the MUC 6 or 7 test
>   or devtest datasets, nor Alan Ritter's Twitter NER data, so all of
>   these remain valid tests of its performance.)
>
> **3 class:    Location, Person, Organization**
>
> **4 class:    Location, Person, Organization, Misc**
>
> **7 class:    Location, Person, Organization, Money, Percent, Date, Time**
>
> These models each use distributional similarity
>   features, which provide some performance gain at the cost of
>   increasing their size and runtime. Also available are the same models
>   missing those features.

---

You might also be interested in

- CoNLL 2003, http://www.cnts.ua.ac.be/conll2003/ner/
- NE tagsets from NLTK [relextract.py](https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/4e59677df364841c1a23dabfde0317388997aa6d/nltk/sem/relextract.py#L31)

Answer (score 1):

This depends on the language, statistical models used, whether you are using the tokensregex fine-grained NER, etc.

For English with the default configuration (including numeric NER and SUTime), you get these 12 entity types mentioned at the top of [the CoreNLP NERClassifierCombiner page](http://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/ner.html) – plus O for not-an-entity:

> Recognizes named (PERSON, LOCATION, ORGANIZATION, MISC), numerical (MONEY, NUMBER, ORDINAL, PERCENT), and temporal (DATE, TIME, DURATION, SET) entities.

If you add the fine-grained tokensregex NER, you also get:

> CAUSE_OF_DEATH, CITY, COUNTRY, CRIMINAL_CHARGE, EMAIL, IDEOLOGY, NATIONALITY, RELIGION, STATE_OR_PROVINCE, TITLE, URL

Comment: thanks a lot @Christopher Manning  , this is quite informative.